# How to ensure that a figure is true if format of both cells are different in Excel?

Tags: excel, exact-match

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qpvk.png)

When I use the exact formula to ensure that two figures matches in Ms Excel 2010 the answer gets false.This is because the two cells I am matching are of different formats.You can refer to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the values match regardless of formatting, use the formula: `=Q4=K4`.

Answer (score 0):

Exact is generally used for comparing strings. It looks like you are comparing 2 numbers. Use an IF to check this

Try `IF(Q4=K4,"Match","Not a match")`

If you want to round off, that is avoid decimal then try this.

```
IF(ROUNDDOWN(Q4,0.1)=ROUNDDOWN(K4,0.1),"Match", "Not a match")
```